# Failing in batch powershell

Tags: powershell, batch

I have a powershell command that runs fine.

```
$(Get-Item c:\0\01.txt).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "01/22/2002 11:11 am")
```

I'd like to use it multiple time. Using a batch file. Before the batch file I used this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

The batch contains commands like this one:

```
powershell -Command "$(Get-Item c:\0\01.txt).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "01/22/2003 11:11 am")"
```

The batch file fails, I got two error messages per command:

```
Get-Date : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '11:11'.
At line:1 char:49
+ $(Get-Item c:\0\01.txt).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date <<<<  01/22/2003 11:11 am)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

Exception setting "LastWriteTime": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:1 char:25
+ $(Get-Item c:\0\01.txt). <<<< lastwritetime=$(Get-Date 01/22/2003 11:11 am)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Unfortunately I don't know what is wrong. Can some help me out?

[screenshot of powershell window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zEpB.png)

Comment: Replace one set of double `"`s with single quotes `'`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either escape the inner double quotes with a backslash (because cmd would ***see*** the date time unquoted)

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Item .\01.txt).lastwritetime=(Get-Date \"01/22/2003 11:11 am\")"
```

or exchange the inner double with single quotes (as DavidPostill suggested).

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Item .\01.txt).lastwritetime=(Get-Date '01/22/2003 11:11 am')"
```

Also the `$` are only neccessary when forcing the expression inside a string.